# Knockoutjs setting current item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In this code: http://jsfiddle.net/PDwBF/1/
link to google doesn't work. How to repair it?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.SetCurrent">
        <p data-bind="text: id"></p>
        <div>
            <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Go to google</a>
        </div>    
    </li>
</ul>    

function ViewModel() 
{ 
  var self = this;
  self.SelectedItem = ko.observable();
  self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.SetCurrent = function(item) 
  {
      self.SelectedItem(item);
  };
};  

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm); 

vm.Items.push({id: 55});
vm.Items.push({id: 66});
vm.Items.push({id: 77});
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you add a link outside of the <ul>, that link works. Curious.

Comment: I need a link inside <li>, it's autogenerated with `data-bind="attr: {href : SomeCode()}"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to return true; from your SetCurrent methood, which will 
allow the default action to proceed like: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PDwBF/3/

Thanks to `rpn` https://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/6ef1081249377728

Answer (score 0):

If you add a return true - it works.

e.g.

```
function ViewModel() 
{ 
  var self = this;
  self.SelectedItem = ko.observable();
  self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.SetCurrent = function(item) 
  {
      self.SelectedItem(item);
      return true;
  };
};
```